# Using IntelliJ Java Code has minimal errors but won't compile? Not sure how to fix. (Newbie)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

This is what I am getting after I compile my code but it doesn't come up with any errors when I am actually typing my code. So when I think it is all good to go and good to run it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. I'm still really new to Java.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant      Size.34.96
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:273)
    at Size.valueOf(Size.java:5)
    at FindAShirt.loadShirt(FindAShirt.java:158)
    at FindAShirt.main(FindAShirt.java:22)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
public record Shirt (String productName, long productCodeNumber, int price, String brand, Size size, int minPrice, int maxPrice) {
    /**
     * constructor to create a Shirt object
     *
     * @param productName       the shirt's name
     * @param productCodeNumber the shirt's code number - unique 9-digit number
     * @param price             the shirt's price
     * @param brand             the shirt's brand
     * @param size              the shirt's size
     * @param minPrice          the users min price they will pay for a shirt
     * @param maxPrice          the users max price they will pay for a shirt
     */
    public Shirt {
    }
//getters

/**
 * @return the shirt's name
 */
public String productName() {
    return productName;
}

/**
 * @return the shirt's code number - unique 9-digit number
 */

public long productCodeNumber() {
    return productCodeNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the shirt's price
 */

public int price() {
    return price;
}

/**
 * @return the shirt's brand
 */

public String brand() {
    return brand;
}


/**
 * @return the shirt's size via enum
 */

public Size size() {
    return size;
}

//create min and max price setters and getters

/**
 * @return a 'dream' shirt's min price
 */
public int minPrice() {
    return minPrice;
}

/**
 * @return a 'dream' shirt's max price
 */
public int maxPrice() {
    return maxPrice;
}



/**
 * enum representing the 8 t-shirt sizes that the geek store stocks
 */
enum Size {
    XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL, XXXXL;

    public String toString() {
        return switch (this) {
            case XS -> "Extra Small";
            case S -> "Small";
            case M -> "Medium";
            case L -> "Large";
            case XL -> "Extra Large";
            case XXL -> "2XL";
            case XXXL -> "3XL";
            case XXXXL -> "4XL";
        };
    }
}
```

Please let me know if adding the code helps. They are all sectioned into parts just like I have them in IntelliJ.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are calling `valueOf()` on an `enum` named `Size` somewhere, and passing it an invalid value. Without seeing your source code, it's impossible to give you a more detailed answer - so post your source code if you need to know more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not a compilation error but a runtime error (i.e. it was discovered when running the program but the syntax of your code is correct)
2. The error is on line 158 of FindAShirt.java as indicated in [the stacktrace you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)
3. It seems that you call something like `Size.valueOf("somesize")` on that line and `somesize` is not a valid value for the `Size` enum.
4. You need to include the code in your question to get the best answers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Now that you have posted your code, I suggest you make it more error-proof with this:

```
Size size;
try {
  size = Size.valueOf(elements[2]);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  System.out.println(elements[2] + " is not a valid Size");
  //and here you may want to exit or use a default value etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. I have added the code in to hopefully explain my issues a bit better. If you have any other advice I would very much appreciate it. Ive been trying to finish this for 5 days now and I am going crazy.  :(

Comment: I suspect the culprit is `size = Size.valueOf(elements[2]);` and `elements[2]` contains an illegal value. You could print the value of `elements[2]` before that line and see the last value before the exception.

Comment: Thank you! That's so helpful. Is there any reason why my import javax.swing.JOptionPane; isn't working? :(

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question with only the code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I did just that. Thanks for all of your help and advice.